# Duda entre Conversion entre Objetos

Tags: c#, poo, conversión-de-tipos, cast

`Square` es una clase que hereda todos los métodos, atributos, propiedades de la clase `Polygon`.

**Existen conversiones de un tipo a otro, como los siguientes ejemplos:**

```
Polygon polygon = new Square(4.5f);  
if (polygon is Square) { 
    Square square = (Square)polygon;//We can now do what we want with the square.
 }
```

**Otro ejemplo de conversión de objetos de un tipo a otro:**

```
Polygon polygon = new Square(4); 
Square square = polygon as Square;
```

Se supone que en el ejemplo número 2: polygon es una variable de tipo `Polygon` que hace referencia a un objeto de tipo `Cuadrado`, pero.. no entiendo cómo es el proceso de conversión de objetos, quisiera una explicación detallada.

Comment: *no entiendo cómo es el proceso de conversión de objetos*: ¿Cual es la duda exactamente? ¿Es el concepto mismo de herencia que no entiendes? ¿O es mas bien que quieres entender como .NET maneja internamente el asignar una variable con una instancia de un tipo a una variable de otro tipo (si es que copia los datos, etc...)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buen días, lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta a la hora de hacer conversiones entre clases, es su [herencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173149.aspx) y además deberías estar asociado al concepto de [polimorfismo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173152.aspx).

> Conceptualmente, una clase derivada es una especialización de la clase
>   base. Por ejemplo, si tiene una clase base Animal, puede tener una
>   clase derivada denominada Mammal y otra clase derivada denominada
>   Reptile. Mammal es Animal y Reptile es Animal, pero cada clase derivada
>   representa especializaciones diferentes de la clase base.

Tienes que tener en cuenta, como se dice en el ejemplo, el Mammal y el Reptile son animales, por eso a la hora de instanciar un objeto puedes hacer las siguientes acciones:

```
Reptile r1 = new Reptile();
Animal r2 = new Reptile();
Mammal m1 = new Mammal();
Animal m1 = new Mammal();
```

Ahora bien, a la hora de hacer casteos, debes de tener en cuenta que existen [dos tipos de conversiones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173105.aspx), la implícita y la explícita. En este caso la que te interesa es la explícita.

> En los tipos de referencia, se requiere una conversión explícita si
>   debe convertir de un tipo base a un tipo derivado.

Para realizar este tipo de conversión existen dos formas.

```
//Primera forma
Derived d1 = new Derived();
Base b1 = d1 as Base;
//Segunda forma
Derived d2 = new Derived();
Base b2 = (Base)d1;
```

**Explicación de lo anterior**

Ya que creo que esto es lo que buscas lo agrego en este "bloque".

Dos clases, que sean una padre de la otra, pueden convertirse de un tipo a otro, esto lo puedes ver analógicamente con la realidad, por ejemplo, medio de transporte sería la clase base, mientras que bicicleta y automóvil son clases a parte, pero también al mismo tiempo se puede decir son medios de transporte. Al ver una bicicleta, tu puedes decir "Es una bicicleta" o decir "Es un medio de transporte", lastimosamente, las computadoras son tontas, por eso es que tienes que hacer la conversión y así entonces el compilador podrá entender que el objeto es una bicicleta o que es un medio de transporte.

> MedioTransporte <-------> Bicicleta
>
> MedioTransporte <-------> Automóvil

Ahora bien, a nivel de sintaxis, tal y como tu pusiste en la pregunta, y como yo volví a mencionar, existen dos formas de hacer un casteo, simplemente esa es la sintaxis, así como lo ves, no tienes que entender mucho la sintaxis, pues en su momento si hubieran querido los desarrolladores de C# hubieran podido utilizar una sintaxis diferente (palabras diferentes en orden diferente), pero escogieron esa forma.

Su comportamiento interno es parecido (si no es que igual) a sobrecargar una clase con el operador `explicit` (ver más abajo los ejemplos). Ahora bien sí lo que quieres es saber cual es más eficiente que otra, ahí sí no sabría darte una respuesta.

**Fin de la Explicación**

Ahora bien otra funcionalidad que tienes es que puedes crear tu misma conversión entre objetos que tal vez no tengan una relación de herencia ([aquí te dejo la explicación que Microsoft da](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xhbhezf4.aspx)), pero que tu quieras que se puedan convertir (cabe mencionar que esto se puede en C# pues maneja el `explicit` como un operador el cual se puede sobrecargar, no sabría decirte sí se puede en otros lenguajes)

y aquí te dejo un ejemplo tomado de [dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/explicit)

```
class Apartment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator House(Apartment a)
    {
    return new House() { Name = a.Name };
    }
}

class House
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator Apartment(House h)
    {
    return new Apartment() { Name = h.Name };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    House h = new House();
    h.Name = "Broadway";

    // Cast a House to an Apartment.
    Apartment a = (Apartment)h;

    // Apartment was converted from House.
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

> Broadway

Ahora bien, después de leer la pregunta una segunda vez, y analizando tal vez una duda que te pueda surgir, es de cual es la diferencia entre tener un objeto base o un objeto derivado.

1. [Sobrecarga de métodos](http://www.genbetadev.com/cnet/sobrecargando-los-metodos-en-c)

Imagina que tienes una clase Animal y una clase Mamifero, los dos con un método ToString(). Puedes sobrecargar el método, para que dependiendo de la instancia, se muestre un mensaje diferente.

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Animal am = new Mamifero();
Mamifero m = new Mamifero();
print(a.ToString());
print(am.ToString());
print(m.ToString());
```

**Salida**

> Soy un animal
>
> Soy un mamifero
>
> Soy un mamifero

2. Agregar métodos y atributos

La clase derivada podría tener más métodos y atributos, además de los que ya le ha heredado la clase base.

3. Agrupación de Datos

Con el polimorfismo, puedes tener un arreglo de datos, que guarde objetos de tipo animal y en el guardar tanto objetos de la clase base, como de las clases derivadas.

**Posdata**

Como última recomendación, deberías de tener claro en donde usar la herencia:

- La jerarquía de herencia representa una relación de identidad y no una relación de pertenencia.
- Se puede volver a utilizar código de las clases base.
- Es necesario aplicar la misma clase y los mismos métodos a tipos de datos diferentes.
- La jerarquía de clases es poco profunda y es poco probable que otros programadores agreguen muchos más niveles.
- Desea realizar cambios globales en clases derivadas modificando una clase base.

Comment: muy bien explicado ^^

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, esperemos haya servido para el OP

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, realmente pese a no haber trabajado mucho con C# creo que a lo que te refieres es al concepto de los lenguajes orientados a objetos.

Realmente no hay ninguna conversión en el código que tú has mostrado, por tanto ese concepto de "conversión de objetos" es erróneo.

Bien, hay que partir de la base de que Polygon es la clase padre y Square la hija. ¿Qué quiere decir esto? Que todos los Square son Polygon, pero no todos los Polygon son Squares.

Un polígono es un objeto que contiene aristas, por tanto, si tiene 4 estaríamos hablando de un cuadrado (que sigue siendo un polígono) y un hexágono (que también es un polígono).

Este concepto hay que tenerlo muy claro, ya que es la base de la orientación a objetos.

Si te fijas, en el código que tú has puesto estás creando un objeto Polygon al que le dices que es un Square(), no al revés. Por tanto no es una conversión a otro objeto, sino que estás especificando QUÉ clase de Polygon estás creando.

Te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a la herencia de clases en Programación Orientada a Objetos para poder clarificar un poco este tema. Si no me expliqué del todo bien o falta algo te ayudar

[Herencia (informática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herencia_(inform%C3%A1tica))