# convertir un objeto de un modelo a otro modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema al querer convertir un objeto a otro siendo estos los modelos iguales pero en diferente `namespace`.

Explicándome mejor, tengo dos proyectos en una solución cada uno con su modelo en el cual tengo ese modelo repetido (`AdminModel`) estoy pasando esa variable de `Session` y convertirlo

Este es el modelo inicial del objeto.

```
namespace Admin.ModeloAdmin{

    public class AdminModel
    {
        public string devKey { get; set; }
        public string mobileKey { get; set; }
        public string cuenta { get; set; }
        public int idCliente { get; set; }
        public int idCuenta { get; set; }
        public int idEmpresa { get; set; }
        public int regreso { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Deseo convertirlo a este otro modelo

```
namespace User.ModeloAdmin{

    public class AdminModel
    {
        public string devKey { get; set; }
        public string mobileKey { get; set; }
        public string cuenta { get; set; }
        public int idCliente { get; set; }
        public int idCuenta { get; set; }
        public int idEmpresa { get; set; }
        public int regreso { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Pero al querer convertirlo me marca un error en la siguiente linea:

```
AdminModel sesionManage = (AdminModel) Session["sessionManage"];
```

**¿Como puedo pasar los datos de un modelo a otro?**

este es el mensaje de error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
>
> No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'AdmixDescargas.Models.AdminModel' al tipo 'DescargaSU.Models.AdminModel'.
>
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidCastException: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'AdmixDescargas.Models.AdminModel' al tipo 'DescargaSU.Models.AdminModel'.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 31:                 else
>
> Línea 32:                 {
>
> Línea 33:                     sesionManage = (AdminModel)HttpContext.Session["sessionManage"];
>
> Línea 34:                 }
>
> Línea 35:
>
> Archivo de origen: C:\Users\juan.gonzalez\Documents\JuanGonzalez\PruebasMVC\AdmixPortal\AdmixDescargas\AdmixDescargas\Areas\DescargaSU\Controllers\InicioController.cs    Línea: 33
>
> Seguimiento de la pila:
>
> [InvalidCastException: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'AdmixDescargas.Models.AdminModel' al tipo 'DescargaSU.Models.AdminModel'.]
>          DescargaSU.Controllers.InicioController.Index(String Sesion) in C:\Users\juan.gonzalez\Documents\JuanGonzalez\PruebasMVC\AdmixPortal\AdmixDescargas\AdmixDescargas\Areas\DescargaSU\Controllers\InicioController.cs:33
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +103
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Claro, necesitas tener referenciada la otra clase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cada uno de los modelos son clases separadas, aunque tengan los mismos atributos, lo que puedes hacer es sobrecargar el tipo de conversión que estás intentando hacer (esto lo había explicado muy superficial en otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32962/duda-entre-conversion-entre-objetos/32974#32974)).

Lo que debes hacer es sobrecargar el [operador explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) en la clase que va a realizar el casteo.

En tu caso sería algo así

namespace User.ModeloAdmin{

```
public class AdminModel
{
    public string devKey { get; set; }
    public string mobileKey { get; set; }
    public string cuenta { get; set; }
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
    public int idCuenta { get; set; }
    public int idEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int regreso { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Admin.ModeloAdmin(User.ModeloAdmin a)
    {
      Admin.ModeloAdmin modelo = new Admin.ModeloAdmin();
      modelo.devKey = a.devKey;
      //asignas cada valor
      return modelo;
   }
}
```

}

Haces lo mismo con la otra clase y así puedes convertir de un tipo al otro y viceversa.

Aquí te dejo otro ejemplo tomado de [dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/explicit)

```
class Apartment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator House(Apartment a)
    {
    return new House() { Name = a.Name };
    }
}

class House
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator Apartment(House h)
    {
    return new Apartment() { Name = h.Name };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    House h = new House();
    h.Name = "Broadway";

    // Cast a House to an Apartment.
    Apartment a = (Apartment)h;

    // Apartment was converted from House.
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

> Broadway

Comment: Al hacer la conversión explicita marcaba el mismo error de que no se podían convertir, con la ayuda de [@Flxtr](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/flxtr) me comento que lo hiciera de este modo `AdminModel sesionManage = Session["sessionManage"] as DescargaSU.Models.AdminModel;` y funciono sin problemas

Comment: Perfecto, que bueno que te sirvió, y también gracias a @Flxtr, por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

**Opcion 1:**

(uso var par inferir el tipo de variable, en una variable temporal.)

```
var tmp_sesionManage = Session["sessionManage"];

// Traduccion a la nueva clase, colocar Espacio de nombre completo para evitar errores
User.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel sesionManage = new User.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel() 
{ devKey = tmp_sesionManage.devKey } // asi llenamos todos los valores
```

**Opcion 2:**

Utilizar [automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Logré obtener lo mismo solo que tal vez de una manera menos optima.

Como son clases practicamente iguales, simplemente serializo y despues la deserializo usando la otra clase.

```
//Creamos objeto de Admin.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel
var adminModel1 = new Admin.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel(ObjetoAdminModel1);

//Serializamos adminModel1 
var adminModel1Serializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(adminModel1);

//Deserializamos usando User.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel
var adminModel2Deserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel>>(adminModel1Serializado);

//Obtenemos el objeto User.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel
User.ModeloAdmin.AdminModel adminModel2 = adminModel2Deserializado;
```

No es lo ideal pero si es funcional

Answer (score 0):

Es algo que quizás puedas usar con mucha frecuencia, a mi lo que me funciona en estos casos es AutoMapper. 
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper
Si no es algo que se hará con frecuencia en tu caso, podrías tan solo copiar las propiedades.

```
var obj = new DescargaSU.Models.AdminModel()
{
    devKey = anotherObj.devKey,
    mobileKey = anotherObj.mobileKey,
    ...
}
```